# String method to integer through parameters with counting

Tags: java

I need to write a static method that takes a String and returns an integer.
Then, return the number of times the letter 'e' appears in the passed in method parameter of type String.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)
        System.out.println("Input text for how many 'e's are inside")
        String e = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

So I have the input but I don't know how to make it a parameter and return the amount of times the letter 'e' is found within the string.

Comment: Well, you said you need to write a method. A new one. If you don't know how exactly it should be done, why don't you start with writing the *signature* of the method? I assume you know what a static method is, how to declare a method's return type and what it means to 'take' a string (in this case, define it as parameter to the method).

Answer (score 0):

There is a elegant want to do that with Java streams,

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input text for how many 'e's are inside");
    String e = scan.nextLine();
    long count = countCharacter(e);
    System.out.println(count);

}

private static long countCharacter(String string) {
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    return IntStream.range(0, chars.length)
                          .mapToObj(i -> chars[i])
                          .filter(c -> c == 'e')
                          .count();
}
```

Comment: you may simplify your answer by using [CharacterSequence#chars()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--)

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        String entry = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(countE(entry)); // Call to function
    }

    // Occurrence of E counter function
    public static int countE (String input) {
        int occurence = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
            if (input.charAt(index) == 'e')
                occurence++;
        }
        return occurence;
    }
}
```